How to avoid using possessive determiners when talking about "taking care of your family" to be more formal and general?

In this society, taking care of your family is the most important.

I want to be more general and formal here, so I'm trying to remove "your". Can I replace the bolded part with the following?

taking care of family
family care
taking care of one's family


"___ care" tends to be used for more restricted senses of "care." "Taking care of ___" just conveys "caring about and tending to ____ in a general way," but "wound care" is first aid, "elder care" is nursing, "child care" is babysitting, etc. "Family care" suggests to me, at first glance, an all-ages medical practice.

the most important (what). Important is also an adjective. Importance is the noun.

I don't think "your family" would be considered informal here. But there seem to be some authorities who forbid certain pronouns (commonly "I", "we", but also sometimes "you"), so I guess you have to follow the rules.

It's not the focus of this question, but I think the premise is questionable. Using "your" this way is understood to be general. And while you might avoid it for the most stringent academic writing, it's not an inappropriately informal usage for most other contexts.

Thank you all! If I want to play it safe, is "caring for families" okay? Because each person usually only has one family, I'm not sure if the phrase is correct.


taking care of family= YES, family is a collective noun and requires no determiner

family care= is not used in this sense of taking care of one's family

taking care of one's family= Sure, one's family, their family, our family. one's is a determiner


But the last one does contain a determiner.

But possessive determiners (one's, your, my,...) are determiners. Also, it's perfectly okay to use taking care of the family in OP's context.

She said she didn't want one. That's how  answered the question.

It would appear from the way the question is framed that OP doesn't realize one's is a "possessive determiner". And it's not obvious they understand that the is also a determiner - which is perfectly natural even in the most formal contexts. It's only really your that's informal (we don't normally use references to me and "non-specific" you in formal text).

I find taking care of family very odd. I accept that there are contexts in which one can use family without a determiner, but this isn't one of them, for me.

Thank you all! So far, "taking care of the/one's family" is the appropriate choice that no one has disagreed with. I hope that there are more suggestions.

@ColinFine It is not odd: Taking care of family can be a burden on some people. Is that odd?

Well, I find it odd. Clearly it occurs.

@ColinFine It's really all over the place: Taking care of pets can be fun. Pets need certain things to be happy and healthy. Read this book to find out what pets need. https://www.benchmarkeducation.com/a0038-caring-for-our-pets-6-pack.html Also in the UK: https://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/news/uk-news/eight-ways-save-up-1200-23580405 All these follow the same pattern.

Except that pets is plural. While family can take a plural verb in UK English, it's not fully plural.
